# How to create a new variable and then, change it with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, dplyr

I'm creating a function with several conditions and now, I want to mutate several variables based on them.

I need to create several variables that correspond to the parity of a woman in that year. First, I created a variable `p2009`, which would be calculated subtracting `p2010` by `V2009` (the number of children that she had in 2009). This interaction creates negative results that I need to replace based on some conditions. For example: if `p2009` is an equal `-1`, I need to readjust the p2009 variable to the total number of children, `TOTALNV` that she had.

To illustrate, imagine someone that in 2010 has a parity equal to 4. She had a child in 2009. So, her p2009 would be 4 (p2010 - 1 (v2009).

These are my functions, sorry, it is pretty horrible.

```
varp2010 <- function(y, w){ #x = p2010, y = V2010, w = TotalNV
  (ifelse(y == 1, w, 
         ifelse(y == 0, 0,
                 ifelse(y == 2, (w-1), 
                        ifelse(y == 3, (w-2), 
                               ifelse(y == 4, (w-3), 
                                      ifelse(y == 5, (w-4),
                                             ifelse(y == 6, (w-5), 0))))))))


varp2009 <- function(y, w, z){
    (ifelse(y == (-1), w, 
          ifelse(y == -2, (w-1), 
                 ifelse(y == -3, (w-2), 
                        ifelse(y == -4, (w-3), 
                               ifelse(y == -5, (w-4),
                                      ifelse(y == -6, (w-5),
                                             ifelse(z == 0, 0, y))))))))
  }
```

I created the variables called sum to be easy to work with 
`sum2008 = TOTALNV-v2010`, `sum2007 = TOTALNV-v2010-v2009`
And this is my mutate function:

```
BH_final_All_Wn <- BH_final_All_Wn %>%  
  mutate(pr2010 = varp2010(y = V2010, w = TOTALNV),
         pr2009 = pr2010 - V2009 %>%
           varp2009(y = pr2009, w = TOTALNV, z = V2009),
         pr2008 = pr2009 - V2008 %>%
           varp2009(y = pr2008, w = sum2008, z = V2008),
         pr2007 = pr2008 - V2007 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr2007, w = sum2007, z = V2007),
         pr2006 = pr2007 - V2006 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr2006, w = sum2006, z = V2006),
         pr2005 = pr2006 - V2005 %>%
           varp2009(y = pr2005, w = sum2005, z = V2005),
         pr2004 = pr2005 - V2004 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr2004, w = sum2004, z = V2004),
         pr2003 = pr2004 - V2003 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr2003, w = sum2003, z = V2003),
         pr2002 = pr2003 - V2002 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr2002, w = sum2002, z = V2002),
         pr2001 = pr2002 - V2001 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr2001, w = sum2001, z = V2001),
         pr2000 = pr2001 - V2000 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr2000, w = sum2000, z = V2000),
         pr1999 = pr2000 - V1999 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr1999, w = sum1999, z = V1999),
         pr1998 = pr1999 - V1998 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr1998, w = sum1998, z = V1998),
         pr1997 = pr1998 - V1997 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr1997, w = sum1997, z = V1997),
         pr1996 = pr1997 - V1996 %>% 
           varp2009(y = pr1996, w = sum1996, z = V1996))
```

My data is too big, around 300000 observations. 
This is a small sample with the variables that I am using.

```
V2010 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
V2009 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
V2008 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
TOTALNV <- c(12, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0)
df <- data.frame(TOTALNV, V2010, V2009, V2008)
```

I will be thankful if someone suggests the​ easiest way to do this.
I am expecting a result like this:

```
  TOTALNV V2010 V2009 V2008 pr2010 pr2009 pr2008
1      12     0     0     0      0      0      0
2       2     1     0     0      2      0      0
3       2     0     1     1      0      2      1
4       0     0     0     0      0      0      0
5       1     1     0     0      1      0      0
6       0     0     0     0      0      0      0
7       0     0     0     0      0      0      0
```

Best

Comment: Please describe your problem without necessarily requiring one to read all the code. Otherwise, take a look at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry. I need to create several variables that correspond to the parity of a woman in that year. First, I create the variable ```p2009```, which would be the parity from ```p2010``` subtracted by ```V2009``` (the number of children that she had in 2009). This interaction creates negative results that I need to replace based on some conditions. For example: if ```p2009``` is an equal ```-1```, I need to readjust the ```p2009``` variable to the total number of children, ```TOTALNV``` that she had.

Comment: Click **edit** above and remove all unnecessary code. Only describe the problem, not code(SPSS)

Comment: You can try to write a function that will do that and apply the function to your data.

Comment: You write that "p2009, which would be calculated subtracting p2010 by V2009 (the number of children that she had in 2009)". Thus p2009 = p2010 - V2009. Your example is "someone that in 2010 has a parity equal to 4. She had a child in 2009. So, her p2009 would be 4 (p2010 - 1 (v2009)". Why? I would think that here p2010= 4, V2009= 1 and thus p2009= 4 - 1 =3

Comment: But I will have some cases where the number will be negative and I must correct for the future.